# VSCode Emmet html boilerplate?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

We used to be able to type `!` inside an html document in vscode to get [html boiler plate content completion as documented here](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/instant-html-boilerplate-in-vscode-with-emmet-3176c0c9ff7e).

However it no longer works.  Thoughts?

I noticed that if we type `!` and select `Edit > Expand Abbreviation`, the `!` is replaced with boilerplate, but I no longer get the intellisense that was there before.

[image]

### Update

Looks like we need to do `ctrl+shift+p` and search for `User Settings`.  Filter for the emmet settings and select the `Trigger expansion on tab` then the `!` is replaced with the corresponding emmet snippet.

I also selected `Show suggestions as snippets`, but the intellisense / snippet is still not showing up.

Comment: Hmmm it works properly for me. Can you confirm that HTML is set prior to trying to use '!'?

Comment: Confirmed it and provided a screenshot.

Comment: Works like charm, thanks. @Ole

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have faced this issue in visual studio.

Step-1:

try below steps in url. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sidthesloth.html5-boilerplate

Step-2:

if it worked : "cheers .!"

else:

it could be issue with select language mode. on the bottom of visual studio next to LF on your screenshot select language mode and change it to html.

Thanks & Regards, Surya kiran.

Answer (score 50):

If you want to get html boilerplate with Emmet Abbreviation, you should type `html:5` and hit tab.

Answer (score 9):

The issue was with Language mode only. You will get the option to select the Langauage mode on the bottom.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is already answered bro, please dont put multiple answers

Answer (score 4):

Been very annoyed for many, many long minutes by the boilerplate shortcut's suddenly, inexplicably not working (maugre much extension-de-installing and intalling and re-installing, even with VS Code uninstalls and re-installs, but what I'm come up with from mining various forums (what *does* seem to work and doesn't appear to be settings-dependent or peculiar to my laptop) is:

1. <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> plus <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (one can just HOLD <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> and type <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>L</kbd> sequentially).
2. In the Emmet Abbreviation window that comes up type <kbd>!</kbd> as usual and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>.
3. Simply striking <kbd>!</kbd> will bring up the boilerplate. One can then simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to return to the code.
4. The two-stroke process of <kbd>!</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> is now replaced by the only marginally more involved five-stroke process of <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>!</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was the "<" problem

this is not working: <html
this is working: html

Answer (score 2):

After a recent update to VS Code the familiar why of getting a html boilerplate failed. You could add a index.html to the file explore and the window would open for its content.

Using Shift and the exclamation mark key would produce it. That is no longer the case instead create your file in the explore. When it opens the window type html, you will receive a dropdown to select from instead.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YThAJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried all the above solutions and nothing works, try resetting the VS Code settings to factory defaults, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

"!" is the symbol for shortcut of html boilerplate. Press "!" and then "Tab" or "Enter" Key. The file should have the extension of ".html". For example the file name should be "name.html".

[The boilerplate by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Och.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue after configuring my VS Code environment for an online course. In my case, the behavior was due to the following pair being added to my settings.json file:

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
```

After I removed this, the shortcuts returned.